# Read mixed types of data from a file with Java

Tags: java, file, input

I am a bit stuck with this code. I have file `file name.txt` which contains following data:

```
BD1               // user ID
Bob Dillon        // user full name
user@email.com    // user Email
10.0              // amount of cash
100               // No.of Points
```

I can't read first and last name of user in the same string. Here is my code:

```
Scanner input_File = new Scanner(new File("customer.txt"));

int num_Customers = 0;
while(input_File.hasNext() && num_Customers < maxLoyalty_CardsQty)
{
    //read ID
    customerID[num_Customers] = input_File.next();
    input_File.nextLine();
    //Here is my problems begins
    while(input_File.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line = input_File.nextLine();
        Scanner line_Scan = new Scanner(line);
        line_Scan.useDelimiter(" ");
        fName[num_Customers] = input_File.next();
        lName[num_Customers] = input_File.next();
        line_Scan.close();
    }
    //read Email
    email[num_Customers] = input_File.next();
    //read Cash
    spendToDate[num_Customers] = input_File.nextDouble();
    //read Points
    points[num_Customers] = input_File.nextInt();
    num_Customers++;
}
input_File.close();
```

Comment: You are using 3 different ways to write the variable name. The one with the space is the wrongest.

Comment: Have you considered using a defined file format such as Json? You could easily parse that into an object with something such as Gson.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using different data layout in the file. It's easier if you have all the required data in a single line, e.g. comma separated especially if you have information about multiple users (and I guess that's the case)

```
FS1, FirstName, LastName, foo@bar.baz, 10.0, 100
```

Then you can go with something like this

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("customer.txt"));
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String[] splitted = scanner.nextLine().split(", ");
             // then you've data in a nice array arranged like below
             // splitted[0] = user Id
             // splitted[1] = first name
             // etc. 
             fName[numCustomers] = splitted[1];
             // ...
             spendToDate[numCustomers] = splitted[3];
}
```

Or you can use Java 8 to simplify this to:

```
new Scanner(new File("customer.txt"))
    .forEachRemaining(line -> {
             String[] splitted = line.split(", ");
             // etc. 
    });
```

or to:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("customer.txt"))
         .forEach(line -> {
             String[] splitted = line.split(", ");
             // splitted[0] = user Id
             // splitted[1] = user name and surname
             // etc. 
         });
```

Also, a friendly advice, make yourself acquainted with Java's [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) it'd make your code much cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: Thank you Kitke for your Code,  Yes this is the One of the ways to do it,But I need to keep file format as it is.it's one of my School project requirements